# display image in window

Tags: c#, wpf

I'd like to display an image in the window that expands automatically to the dimensions of that image.
Right now, I have a code which shows it but I have to enter height and width of the window and the image to display it properly. Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to set `SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight"` property on the window, see the following proof of concept:

```
<Window x:Class="MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight">
<Grid>
    <Image Stretch="None" Source="Images\img1.jpg"/>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course it's possible.
Just before you load the image in your PictureBox control, adjust the size of the control to match the image size, then load the image in PictureBox.

Or even better, let .NET do the job (but this is winforms):

```
pictureBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.AutoSize;
```

For WPF try this in your code (I didn't test though):

```
    image1.Width = width;
    image1.Height = height;
```

where width and height is the size of the picture you try to load.

Comment: But how do I do this in wpf? I use <Image></Image> tags to display the image.

Comment: @bah image1.Width = width;     image1.Height = height; may do the trick you want?

Answer (score 0):

A WPF window can be made to fit to its contents.  In XAML set the [SizeToContent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.sizetocontent.aspx) property to "WidthAndHeight"

```
<Window x:Class ...
        SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight">
```

Now just make sure your Image container sizes to the source image and you should be set.

Comment: Haha, thanks but I'm gonna give points to Mohammed since you have a lot more points :)